# Is it possible to reference scorecard results into another scorecard?

Tags: looker-studio

I have two scorecards, each with a different filter applied. I am currently creating the following percentage calculation, manually:

```
Scorecard A / Scorecard B
```

I would like to be able to automate it. I tried to reference the scorecards into a new scorecard but that did not work. Is there another way?

I want to be able to use result from `Scorecard A` and `Scorecard B` in another scorecard, or get the result by another way. Thank you in advance!

For example:

```
Scorecard A = 10   
Scorecard B = 5
```

Then

```
Scorecard C = Scorecard A / Scorecard B = 2
```

Comment: [As of REVISION 3] **Needs details**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (TO-DO) (and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet (TO-DO)) of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 2) Expected output (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 3) An attempt at solving the issue (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (DONE))? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit your dataset (either through the menus or by clicking the little pencil next to the dataset name in you scorecards).

When the dataset menu comes up, click "ADD A FIELD".

Then you can create a metric which represents scorecard A divided by scorecard B.

So if scorecard A is the sum of metric1 filtered by DimensionX and scorecard B is the sum of metric2 filtered by DimensionY it would be:

```
sum(case when DimensionX = "Filter value" then metric1 else 0 end)/sum(case when DimensionY = "Another filter value" then metric2 else 0 end)
```

The metrics need to be ones that haven't already been aggregated.